# Show that there exists $c \in (a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis

Problem:

> Let $f\colon [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function with $0 < a < b$. Show that there exists some $c \in (a,b)$ such that 
>   $$\frac{1}{b-a} \cdot \begin{vmatrix} f(a) & f(b) \\ a & b \end{vmatrix} = f(c) - c f'(c)$$

It really looks like some intermediate value theorem problem, but I can't figure it out. Can you give me a hint?

/edit: The geometric interpretation could be: let the secant through the values of $f$ in points $a,b$ intersect the $OY$ axis in $A$. Then there exists some $c$, that the tangent to the function in $c$ intersects the $OY$ axis in $C$.

My observation: by the Lagrange theorem, there exists some $x$ that the tangent intersects the axis above the point $A$. It looks sensible (needs a formal proof, though) that there will exist a point $y$ that tangent in $y$ will intersect $OY$ below $A$.

But still it gives us nothing since we don't know whether the function $x \mapsto f(x) - x f'(x)$ has the Darboux property?

Could you help me further?

Answer (score 2):

(Possible) Hint:

$$
\frac{bf(a)-af(b)}{b-a}=\frac{bf(a)-af(a)+af(a)-af(b)}{b-a}=f(a)-a\cdot\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.
$$

Comment: added my tries, see the OP

Comment: What do you mean by "possible hint"? Does this hint work or not...? Have you written down the full proof yourself?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I have not written out the full proof.  I was giving an approach that may work (but also might not).

Comment: I see. Well, -1 from me then. For more info, [see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/22263/10014) (in particular, the first item in Ron Gordon's answer, even though I disagree with his ultimate conclusion).